# Critical Error When Importing invoices - VTiger

Tags: php, mysql, vtiger

We have a working vTiger application that already have hunderds of invoices. We now need to import all our old invoices (around 4500 invoices with all their products and shipping addresses of course).

I've created a script that reads all our old invoices and does the following:

```
- adds a new crmentity to the vtiger_crmentity table
- adds a new invoice to the vtiger_invoice table
- adds a new shipping address to the vtiger_invoiceshipads
- adds a new billing address to the vtiger_invoicebillads
- adds all products to the vtiger_inventoryproductrel
```

So far so good. All seemed to be imported ok at first and all the information is displayed correctly within the invoices.

However, after trying to save new invoices I'm having few problems that seem to be connected:

- When trying to create a new invoice (manually) it looks as if it's saving but then, instead of displaying the new invoice, it displays the last invoice. I've checked the mysql tables and seems as a new crmentity is not being created at all.

  - sometimes when trying to save, it trys to download `index.php` instead of saving.

I think it might be related to the `invoice_no` (custom invoice sequencing), since when imported I left invoice_no column empty.

I've also haven't modified the `vtiger_modentity_num` table at all when importing, could it be related?

Are there any other tables/fields that need to be modified in my scenario?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: wrote a custom importer as well, didn't have any trouble with this, but how did you create the CRM entity id? can you provide some code? I used this `$crmEntityId = $adb->getUniqueID('vtiger_crmentity');`. Later had inserts in the following tables: vtiger_crmentity, vtiger_inventoryshippingrel, vtiger_invoiceshipads, vtiger_invoicebillads, vtiger_invoice, vtiger_invoicecf, vtiger_inventoryproductrel